# Facing an issue with modules

Tags: android, module, aar

I've created a project with two modules(Module A and Module B).
I've added two aar files in libs folder of Module A now i have tried to use Module A in Module B. but build was failing because Module B is looking for aar files in Module B libs folder but actually those files are in Module A libs folder.

This is the Error what i am getting:

> Could not find com.samplelib:samplelib:.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>     - file:/D:/Projects/sample/module A/libs/samplelib.aar
>   Required by:
>       project :Module B > project :Module A

I am trying to from past 2days but i'm not able to found the solution. 
if any body know the solution please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.